# Index column not resetting after I apply filter in Dax?

Tags: dax

I have table which shows time difference between different types of ID's for when an alert is given. The time since prev will say when the next alert is on the device ID.

my table looks like this:

```
Time                 Device ID      Type           TimeSincePrev(seconds)        index
22.1.21 04:02:04         12         None                 0                         1
22.1.21 04:24:07         13         low                 1320                       2
22.1.21 04:26:04         14          medium            120                        3
......

...
......
...
...
```

However When I filter by deviceID, the indexes will not reset to 1,2,3...., instead, it will go to a random number, causing the timesinceprev alert to be wrong. How do I correct so that index is correct, hopefully correcting the TimeSincePrev column. Also if there is a way to get TimeSincePrev to show seconds via the the seconds and not just via the minute like it is now

This is what the query for the index column looks like:

```
index= COUNTROWS(FILTER(VALUES('Table'[Time]),
                        'Table'[Time]<EARLIER('Table'[Time])
    ))+1
```

Here is how TimeSincePrev:

```
TimeSincePrev= IF(DATEDIFF(LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Time],'Table'[index], 

'Table'[index]-1),MINUTE)>720,BLANK(),DATEDIFF(LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Time], 

'Table'[index],'Table'[index]-1),'Table'[Time],MINUTE))*60
```

How do I get it so when I filter by device ID the indexes don't mess up like this:

```
Time                 Device ID      Type           TimeSincePrev(seconds)        index
22.1.21 04:02:04         12         None                 0                         6
22.1.21 04:24:07         12         low                 1320                       3
22.1.21 04:26:04         12         medium            120                          1
22.1.21 04:02:04         12         None                 0                         2
22.1.21 04:24:07         12         low                 1320                       4
22.1.21 04:26:04         12          medium            120                         5
......

...
......
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a **column** for this? If so, you need to create a measure that handles the indexing instead.

Columns are re-calculated only at refresh time (when you refresh the dataset), NOT at query time (when you click on slicers). The column cannot respond to your selected slicer value and calculate on the fly.

Comment: What would be the best way to create an index measure since I need to use a column in a table. Can you use a measure in a table? and the earlier function can't be used in a measure